# Conflict between mock.patch and unittest.skip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

(Python 3.4.0)

I got this strange error, which took me a while to debug:

---

user.py

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


def new_user(name):
    user = User(name)
```

---

test.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from user import new_user

@patch('user.User')
class TestUser(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skip
    def test_new_user(self, mockUser):
        new_user('Frank')
        mockUser.assert_called_once_with('Frank')


unittest.main()
```

---

Running it will crash:

```
» python test.py 
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_new_user (__main__.TestUser)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1125, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
TypeError: decorator() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Removing the skip will let it run normally. It seems `patch` and `skip` do not stack well. Is this correct, or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unittest.skip` requires a string argument of its own, the reason for skipping the test.

```
@unittest.skip("Not yet ready to test")
def test_new_user(self, mockUser):
    new_user('Frank')
    mockUser.assert_called_once_with('Frank')
```

The interaction you are seeing comes from the `skip` decorator consuming the method itself as the `reason` argument (`def skip(reason):`), which results in `test_new_user` being bound to a one-argument function defined inside the decorator, not the two-argument function you define in the test case.

Note that if you left your call to `skip` in place and commented out the `patch` instead, your test would still pass, despite `test_new_user` seemingly not receiving its `mockUser` argument.

---

`unittest.skip` itself is technically not a decorator; it is a function which *returns* a decorator, which is then applied to `test_new_user`. Using regular function-call syntax, your code does

```
def test_new_user(self, mockUser):
    ...
test_new_user = unittest.skip(test_new_user)
```

when what you need is

```
test_new_user = unittest.skip("my reason")(test_new_user)
```

Your `test_new_user` is being bound to the decorator itself, not the decorated method.

Comment: Makes sense, but I have seen the `skip` decorator being used often without any `reason` ...

Comment: Techinically, it's incorrect. It's a side effect of how `skip` works that replacing the method with the decorator instead of the decorated method has the same effect. In your case, though, you weren't supplying the method that `patch` expects.

Comment: I see; so this seems to be a python syntax problem, right? Since python takes the function to be decorated as first parameter for the decorator, it does not realize that the mandatory `reason` parameter is missing, and creates a broken mess instead of pointing to the real problem: `TypeError: skip() missing 1 required positional argument: reason`